# Wordpress: no action on submit button when get_header() is used

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, html

I'm building a form and have the following problem. The form perfectly works when `get_header()` is not used in my php code. Once I include this function into the document, clicking on the `submit` button doesn't do anything.

- the page with `get_header()` included, TwentySixteen default theme: http://eventboss.org/add-item-with-header/
- the page without `get_header()`: http://eventboss.org/add-property/

How can I make the `Post Review` (Submit button) work with `get_header()` in the code? And what is the best way to track these errors in future? I see no error in my browser console. Many thanks in advance.

UPD. The page source code:

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Rate Wine Form Header
*/
?>
<?php
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

 // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $error = "";

     if (!empty($_POST['title'])) {
      $title = $_POST['title'];
     } else {
      $error .= "Please add a title<br />";
    }

     if (!empty($_POST['description'])) {
      $description = $_POST['description'];
     } else {
     $error .= "Please add a description<br />";
    }

     if (!empty($_POST['post_tags'])) {
      $post_tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
     } else {
      $error .= "Please add some keywords<br />";
    }

  if (!empty($_POST['winerating'])) {
      $post_tags = $_POST['winerating'];
     } else {
      $error .= "Please add some keywords<br />";
    }
  // IMAGE VALIDATION - CHECK IF THERE IS AN IMAGE AND THAT ITS THE RIGHT FILE TYPE AND RIGHT SIZE
  if ($_FILES) {
   foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    //Check if the $_FILES is set and if the size is > 0 (if =0 it's empty)

    if(isset($_FILES[$file]) && ($_FILES[$file]['size'] > 0)) {

     $tmpName = $_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'];
     list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($tmpName);

    /*if($width!=10 || $height!=10)
    {
     $error .= "Image is to small<br />";
     unlink($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']);
    }*/

    // Get the type of the uploaded file. This is returned as "type/extension"
                $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($_FILES[$file]['name']));
                $uploaded_file_type = $arr_file_type['type'];

                 // Set an array containing a list of acceptable formats
                $allowed_file_types = array('image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png');

                 // If the uploaded file is the right format
                if(in_array($uploaded_file_type, $allowed_file_types)) {

    } else { // wrong file type
        $error .= "Please upload a JPG, GIF, or PNG file<br />";
                     }

    } else {
    $error .= "Please add an image<br />";
    }
   } // end for each
  } // end if

  $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
  $winerating = $_POST['winerating'];

  // ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
  if (empty($error)) {
   $new_post = array(
   'post_title' => $title,
   'post_content' => $description,
   'post_category' => array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
   'tags_input' => array($tags),
   'post_status' => 'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
   'post_type' => 'post',  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
   'winerating' => $winerating
  );

  //SAVE THE POST
  $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

        //KEEPS OUR COMMA SEPARATED TAGS AS INDIVIDUAL
  wp_set_post_tags($pid, $_POST['post_tags']);

  //REDIRECT TO THE NEW POST ON SAVE
  $link = get_permalink( $pid );
  wp_redirect( $link );

  //ADD OUR CUSTOM FIELDS
  add_post_meta($pid, 'rating', $winerating, true);
  
  //INSERT OUR MEDIA ATTACHMENTS
        if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
        }
         if ($_FILES) {
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                    return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                }
                $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $pid );
            }   
        }
        if ($attach_id > 0){
            //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
            update_post_meta($pid,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
        }
            
            

   /*//INSERT OUR MEDIA ATTACHMENTS
   if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
    // $newupload returns the attachment id of the file that
     // was just uploaded. Do whatever you want with that now.
    }

   } // END THE IF STATEMENT FOR FILES
   */
   
  } // END SAVING POST
 } // END VALIDATION
} // END THE IF STATEMENT THAT STARTED THE WHOLE FORM

//POST THE POST YO
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');

?>

<?php get_header(); // if this function is included the button doesn't work!!! ?>

  <div id="container">
   <div id="content" role="main">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
     <?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
      <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
     <?php } else { ?>
      <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
     <?php } ?>

     <div class="form-content">
      <?php
      if (!empty($error)) {
       echo '<p class="error"><strong>Your message was NOT sent<br/> The following error(s) returned:</strong><br/>' . $error . '</p>';
      } elseif (!empty($success)) {
       echo '<p class="success">' . $success . '</p>';
      }
     ?>
      <?php the_content(); ?>

  <!-- WINE RATING FORM -->

  <div class="wpcf7">
  <form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" class="wpcf7-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <!-- post name -->
   <fieldset name="name">
    <label for="title">Wine Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="5" name="title" />
   </fieldset>

   <!-- post Category -->
   <fieldset class="category">
    <label for="cat">Type:</label>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'tab_index=10&taxonomy=category&hide_empty=0' ); ?>
   </fieldset>

   <!-- post Content -->
   <fieldset class="content">
    <label for="description">Description and Notes:</label>
    <textarea id="description" tabindex="15" name="description" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
   </fieldset>

   <!-- wine Rating -->
   <fieldset class="winerating">
    <label for="winerating">Your Rating</label>
    <input type="text" value="" id="winerating" tabindex="20" name="winerating" />
   </fieldset>

   <!-- images -->
   <fieldset class="images">
    <label for="bottle_front">Front of the Bottle</label>
    <input type="file" name="bottle_front" id="bottle_front" tabindex="25" />
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset class="images">
    <label for="bottle_rear">Back of the Bottle</label>
    <input type="file" name="bottle_rear" id="bottle_rear" tabindex="30" />
   </fieldset>

   <!-- post tags -->
   <fieldset class="tags">
    <label for="post_tags">Additional Keywords (comma separated):</label>
    <input type="text" value="" tabindex="35" name="post_tags" id="post_tags" />
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Post Review" tabindex="40" id="submit" name="submit" />
   </fieldset>

   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
   <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
  </form>
  </div> <!-- END WPCF7 -->

  <!-- END OF FORM -->
      <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
      <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyten' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
     </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </div><!-- #post-## -->

    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

   </div><!-- #content -->
  </div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using WP Cache plugin, because when you are using `get_header()` function in your file and then submitting form, `_wpcf7_is_ajax_call` field is getting added in your form and it is setting its value to '1', which cause it to send ajax request.

So your form is submitting but submitting via ajax request.

Comment: You were absolutely right except for the fact that it was Contact Form 7 conflicting behavior. No idea how to make Contact Form 7 not contradict with the rest of the forms on the site, still very grateful for you answer. Many thanks!

Comment: there has been some sort of setting to eliminate ajax call in contact form 7